# Python Is it possible to recreate a whole call stack?

Tags: python, python-stackless

I'm interested in experimenting with python. I know I can inspect and inject local and global variables into a frame using `frame.f_locals` and `frame.f_globals`, but I am now itching to create a full call stack.

What is keeping me from just changing the stack information is the fact that python doesn't allow me to change it.

I have actually considered programmatically transforming the python module I am using, in order to simulate winding the stack. But I am aware it is a terrible solution because client code usage of `if`, `while`, `with` and `try` would easily break my code.

I've also looked at manipulating `frame.f_back`, to no avail. It's read-only.

```
>>> import sys
... 
... frm = sys._getframe()
... 
... frm.f_back = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 5, in <module>
    frm.f_back = None
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

## What I'm trying to do

As an experiment, I'm trying to implement `fork()` across a network.

I'm aware stackless python may have what I want, but it's still impossible to change the `frame.f_back` attribute.

Comment: There is more to the python interpreter state than you see directly in the stack trace. Unless you design a program to be able to capture it's state, this is an impossible task with the dynamic nature of python.

Comment: This might only be possible if you modify the interpreter itself.

Comment: I have thought of writing a C extension.

Comment: But modifying the interpreter seems so daunting of a thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Online Python Tutor (http://www.pythontutor.com/). What it does is that it captures frames during execution to create visualization of python code. So, you could use the captured frames.

Comment: I assume it's capturing frames and executed lines using a trace function ([`sys.settrace`](docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace)). But then again the question is about changing/creating frames from python, not just reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> type(sys._getframe())()

TypeError: cannot create 'frame' instances
```

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [AST module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and the [symtable module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/symtable.html)